# TravisCI no audio device

Tags: audio, sdl, alsa, travis-ci

I'm trying to use [TravisCI](http://about.travis-ci.org/) to test a SDL application, which has audio functionality (but the test does not require it).

When I started the app in the Travis's VM, it exited with:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4720:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Could not open sound: No available audio device
```

Is there anything that can emulate an audio device, like [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) can emulate a video device?

Comment: I ran into the same problem as you, and i just caught the error (and did nothing in the catch section). We don't need audio for our tests so now they all pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can load kernel modules, try the driver `snd-dummy`.

Otherwise, tell SDL to use device name `null` (set the environment variable `AUDIODEV`).
(The `null` device does not get the timing correct.)

Comment: Using `export AUDIODEV=null` before launching the app fixed it! I haven't tried using `snd-dummy`, which looks a bit complex to me.

Comment: Travis-CI's virtualization doesn't seem to allow modprobe:
`$ sudo modprobe snd-dummy
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab079.5/modules.dep: No such file or directory
The command "sudo modprobe snd-dummy" failed and exited with 1 during before_install.`